# Adding extra information in JUnit reports

Tags: java, ant, junit, junit4

I am using JUnit4 and want to put some extra information to be displayed in JUnit reports.
For this, I shall be dumping the extra information to the report xml and then modify the xslt to read that extra information to generate the HTML report.

Steps so far that are working are:

1. Copied all the code from XMLJUnitResultFormatter to MyFormatter.java and modified the endTest() method to add that extra information in the form of an extra attribute to testcase XML tag.
   This is really bad :( but I could not simply override it as there usages of the private instance variables directly without getters/setters in endTest() method.

My junit ant task:

```
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
        <!--<formatter type="xml"/>-->
        <formatter classname="com.some.junit.MyFormatter" extension=".xml"/>
        <test name="com.some.source.MyTestClassTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="JUnitProject.classpath"/>
    </junit>
```

2. Modified the xslt to read the extra attribute of TESTCASE xml tag and display in report.

My modified ant task for report:

```
<target name="junitreport" depends="MyTestClassTest">
    <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
        </fileset>
        <report styledir="reportstyle" format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

I came across using TestNG nor SureFire Maven plugins as solutions, but I can't use them in my project.

Is there any better way than this in JUnit4?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe?

The interface `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitResultFormatter` is what needs to be implemented for a custom output format. This could write to any output stream, which is all the extensiblity that was built into the framework. You are right, there isn't a good way to extend the capabilities of `XMLJUnitResultFormatter` to customize the output. A copy-paste-modify certainly isn't ideal, but certainly acceptable.

Another approach might be to have more than one `formatter` defined in your `ant` task. One could be the regular `xml` formatter, with another being your custom one for additional information. These two files could be combined and then turned into HTML using `xsl` transforms.

I leave it to you to decide if this a *better* method than you had devised.